# Redis as a distributed cache not performing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a fairly complex asp.net site that builds up pages on the fly( like WordPress I suppose ). It relies heavily on caching to keep things nice and zippy ( 0.5 second response times ).

I recently took it upon myself to load balance the app and in doing so needed to get the cache into a distributed environment ( I am already using SQL Server Session State ). So I did the research, opted for redis, and chose the StackExchange.Redis client.

I kept my objects very simple, small objects with "type_dbIndex" key naming convention and then linked all the objects that have relationships using sets. I commissioned a Ubuntu box dedicated to redis only and was very exited to flip the switch. Unfortunately I was severely underwhelmed. It turns out that my redis cache was on average 3 times slower than the in-memory cache ( 1.5 seconds ).

Now I'll be the first to admit that I am no redis expert, just the basic install and setup, but I also don't have time to become a redis tuning guru to try and squeeze a second out of it. I can imagine that the real culprit though is network latency. On average around 100-200 objects are loaded from the cache on each request, all of them requiring to be serialized/deserialized and pushed across the network ( servers are in same DMZ using local network ).

So to my question, am I getting uncommonly bad results, or is this the norm? Do I need to write custom serializers for all my objects? Should I use ProtoBuf instead of standard serializers. Do i need to create an internal network between the two machines ( dedicated network cards like we did between SQL & Web Server in the old days )? Basically, is there any hope of getting down to the golden half second mark, because managing the in-process memory cache between load balanced servers is a nightmare to the point of being completely impractical. Am I using the cache incorrectly?

I appreciate any advice / help / war stories.

EDIT : I thought I would paste a miniprofiler output here so you can further see my conundrum...

[image: Miniprofiler Outputs]

Comment: What is the average network latency between the app and the Redis server? What is the average size of a cached object?

Comment: @ItamarHaber - Unfortunately i have no idea of the actual network latency. ( tell me how and I will measure ), but the objects in cache are relatively small, maybe 20 properties all simple types ( no lists etc )

Comment: As you can see on average I am getting a 100ms response time to a simple Get call by key...I was hoping for below 10ms

Comment: Try pinging your Redis server, or even better use redis-cli --latency

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not redis, but hitting redis over the network 100-200 times.
Try these inbuilt redis solutions:

1. Pipelining : This enables to send redis requests in batch, and fetch all the data in one ( or few more ) network requests.

http://redis.io/topics/pipelining

2. Lua scripting : Server side Lua scripting lets you send Lua code to redis server, get evaluated there, and return the data in single network request.

In your particular case, pipeline would be most effective solution, it is available with all redis drivers like python,php etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant really batch up the calls because they are made "on demand" and change vastly from request to request. I did however remove the "Exists" check and replace it with a single get and check for null and that pretty much reduced the calls by half, but it's still too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a hybrid caching model using in-memory cache and redis together. All cache methods (get,exists etc) should also use in-memory cache, if the item does not exists in memory cache, query item from redis and add it to memory cache for further requests.

This can cause inconsistency between client nodes but will increase the performance for cache operations.

Example code taken from [nopCommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the value to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The value associated with the specified key.</returns>
    public virtual T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        //little performance workaround here:
        //we use "MemoryCacheManager" to cache a loaded object in memory for the current HTTP request.
        //this way we won't connect to Redis server 500 times per HTTP request (e.g. each time to load a locale or setting)
        if (_memoryCacheManager.IsSet(key))
            return _memoryCacheManager.Get<T>(key);

        var rValue = _db.StringGet(key);
        if (!rValue.HasValue)
            return default(T);
        var result = Deserialize<T>(rValue);

        _memoryCacheManager.Set(key, result, CacheProfiles.ShortLivedDuration);
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified key and object to the cache.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">key</param>
    /// <param name="data">Data</param>
    /// <param name="cacheTime">Cache time</param>
    public virtual void Set(string key, object data, int cacheTime)
    {
        if (data == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            return;

        var entryBytes = Serialize(data);
        var expiresIn = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cacheTime);

         _db.StringSetAsync(key, entryBytes, expiresIn);
        _memoryCacheManager.Set(key, data, cacheTime);
    }
```